# ASP.NET MVC API Action Returning 404, All Other Actions Work

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404

I have an angular app that is calling a ASP.NET WEB API. I have added a method on to one of the api controllers and it is returning a 404. Every other method on the same controller can be called with no issues. The application is hosted locally on IIS.

API Action:

```
[ActionName("GetOrgChart")]
[ResponseType(typeof(List<Object>))]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GetOrgChart(string id)
{
    EmployeeMasterPTOCoordinator emPTOCnator = new EmployeeMasterPTOCoordinator();
    List<Object> orgChartData = emPTOCnator.GetOrgChart()
    return Ok<List<Object>>(orgChartData);
}
```

HTTP Post Call From Angular App:

```
function GetOrgChart(id) {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   $http({
        method: 'POST', cache: false,
        url: 'localhost:81/api/Employee/EmployeeMaterPTO/GetOrgChart',
        data: id
    }).success(function(data){
        deffered.resolve(data);
    }).error(function(data){
        deffered.resolve(data);
    })
    return deffered.promise;
}
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this? I have tried removing the api from the application pool in IIS and re adding it. I have looked all over stack overflow and have not been able to find a solution

Answer (score 1):

Remove [HttpPost] and replace [ActionName] with this

```
[Route("~/api/Employee/EmployeeMaterPTO/GetOrgChart/{id?}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetOrgChart(string id)
```

Add to the top of your route.config

```
 routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

and remove   " data: id  " from request

```
method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:81/api/Employee/EmployeeMaterPTO/GetOrgChart/'+id
```

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work for me. I have a feeling it is due to dll files not updating when I change the c# code.

Comment: It is http since I am developing locally. Full url is : 'http://localhost:81/api/Employee/EmployeeMaterPTO/GetOrgChart'

Comment: @JacobNarayan Yes, I believe a rebuild will be necessary for any of your API route changes to be published for consumption by your client.